# How to handle short hash with longer order of base point in ECDSA

Tags: java, security, bouncycastle, elliptic-curve, ecdsa

I am using CVC certificates (If you haven't heard about them, pretend they are X509) with Elliptic curve signature with brainpool256r1 curve and SHA1 hash. In java with bouncycastle, I simply verify them like this:

```
Signature sign = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withECDSA", "BC");
sign.initVerify(key);
sign.update(certificate_data_to_be_verified);
sign.verify(signature);
```

And everything works fine. However, I need to verify them also in an embedded device, and I have encountered a problem, because I am supposed to use leftmost 256bits of hash to get the value of `z`  at least according to [wikipedia ECDSA article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_DSA). But SHA1 has only 160bits.

How is this solved by bouncycastle, and is there some general theory on how to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing an order of base point with a key length.

Here is how [Bouncy Castle code](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/crypto/signers/ECDSASigner.java#L139) performs ECDSA digital signature verification.

```
private BigInteger calculateE(BigInteger n, byte[] message)
{
    /* n is curve order value */
    int log2n = n.bitLength();
    /* and message is a hash */
    int messageBitLength = message.length * 8;

    BigInteger e = new BigInteger(1, message);
    /* If message is longer than curve order */
    if (log2n < messageBitLength)
    {
        /* only log2n bits are taken from the left */
        e = e.shiftRight(messageBitLength - log2n);
    }
    return e;
}
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion, but if I understand it correctly now, having the brainpoolp256r1 curve means I have 256bits order of base (meaning 512bit key) and using that, I can have SHA1 hash in bouncycastle without it complaining. Is there anything I am still missing?

Comment: I've updated an answer. You should also change a question to mention that your key is based on curve from brainpoolp256r1 family.

Comment: Thanks for update, I updated my questiom, hope it makes more sense now. So basically what that means, the value of `e` (`z` in my question) is padded with zeroes from left in the case I described?

Comment: Well, that I believe means the same. :)